# Кто может подсказать как сделать Dropdopwn menu связанное с профилем?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

Хочу сделать такое меню как в ВК.. Нажимаешь на кнопку с иконкой профиля, появляется меню. Я уже сколько ищу, но никак не могу найти как такое реализовать.. Если кто делал подобное, то помогите пожалуйста.[image: Я про эту кнопку говорю]

Сам профиль делаю через Django

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Comment: Спасибо, поищу здесь